# How to serialize a Set <Entity> as a String Array in ElasticSearch using Hibernate-Search?

Tags: java, hibernate, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, hibernate-search

I am using [hibernate-search](http://hibernate.org/search/documentation/getting-started/) to map my entities to both MySQL and ElasticSearch.

There is a discrepancy between how I want the elasticsearch documents to be indexed and how they are actually indexed.

I have an entity called `Product` with a set of `ProductImage`. I would like that the `ProductImage` entities were serialized as an Array of Strings in the elasticsearch index.

---

#### I have this:

**Relational world (MySQL):**

```
> Product table
______________________________
| gtin | price | other_stuff |
------------------------------
```

```
> ProductImage table
_______________
| gtin | path |
---------------
```

**No-Relational world (Elasticsearch index):**

```
http://elasticsearch.domain.com/products/com.example.Product/_search
{
    "gtin" : "1234"
    "images" : [
        { 
            "path" : "http://image.host.com/product-image-1"
        }, 
        { 
            "path" : "http://image.host.com/product-image-2"
        }
    ]
}
```

---

#### But I want this:

```
http://elasticsearch.domain.com/products/com.example.Product/_search
{
    "gtin" : "1234"
    "images" : [
        "http://image.host.com/product-image-1",
        "http://image.host.com/product-image-2"
    ]
}
```

**This is my implementation:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
@Indexed(index = "products")
public class Product implements Serializable {

    @Id
    String gtin;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "gtin", referencedColumnName = "gtin")
    @IndexedEmbedded
    Set<ProductImage> images = new TreeSet<>();

}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product_images")
public class ProductImage implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    @Field
    @FieldBridge(impl = IdBridge.class)
    //@ContainedId <- also tried something with this
    Id id;

    public Id getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Id id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Embeddable
    public static class Id implements Serializable {

        String gtin;

        @Field
        //@ContainedId <- also tried something with this
        String path;

        public String getGtin() {
            return gtin;
        }

        public void setGtin(String gtin) {
            this.gtin = gtin;
        }

        public String getPath() {
            return path;
        }

        public void setPath(String path) {
            this.path = path;
        }
    }

    public static class IdBridge implements StringBridge {
        @Override
        public String objectToString(Object object) {
            Id id = (Id) object;
            return id.getPath();
        }
    }

}
```

**How could I do to index the Product Images as a simple array of String within the Product?**

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the `@IndexedEmbedded` with a bridge.

Define the bridge:

```
public class ProductImageSetPathBridge implements MetadataProvidingFieldBridge {

    @Override
    public void configureFieldMetadata(String name, FieldMetadataBuilder builder) {
        builder.field( name, FieldType.STRING );
    }

    @Override
    public void set(String fieldName, Object value, Document document, LuceneOptions luceneOptions) {
        if ( value != null ) {
            indexNotNullIterable( fieldName, value, document, luceneOptions );
        }
    }

    private void indexNotNullIterable(String name, Object value, Document document, LuceneOptions luceneOptions) {
        Iterable<?> collection = (Iterable<?>) value;
        for ( Object entry : collection ) {
            indexEntry( name, entry, document, luceneOptions );
        }
    }

    private void indexEntry(String fieldName, Object entry, Document document, LuceneOptions luceneOptions) {
        ProductImage image = (ProductImage) entry;
        if ( image != null ) {
            luceneOptions.addFieldToDocument( fieldName, image.getId().getPath(), document );
        }
    }

}
```

And apply it in the right place, in the `Product` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
@Indexed(index = "products")
public class Product implements Serializable {

    @Id
    String gtin;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "gtin", referencedColumnName = "gtin")
    // Remove this @IndexedEmbedded
    //@IndexedEmbedded
    // And put this instead
    // Don't forget analyze = Analyze.NO, because you probably don't want an URL to be analyzed
    @Field(bridge = @FieldBridge(impl = ProductImageSetPathBridge.class), analyze = Analyze.NO)
    Set<ProductImage> images = new TreeSet<>();

}
```

More information about bridges:

- [Custom field bridges](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.10/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-custom-bridges)
- [Metadata-providing field bridges](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.10/reference/en-US/html_single/#metadata-providing-field-bridge)
- [Bridges in the Elasticsearch integration](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.10/reference/en-US/html_single/#_custom_field_bridges)